# Minimum number of Groups needed to convert the given Array to another Array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have a given array with unique values say `[1,4,3,2]` and another desired array `[1,2,4,3]`

I want to cut this input array into a minimum number of pieces so I can convert that to the desired array by just re-arranging the cut pieces.

So for the input array `[1,4,3,2]` I can cut into pieces `(1), (4,3), (2)` and re-arrange like `(1),(2),(4,3)` to get the desired array `[1,2,4,3]`

**Constraints:**

```
Array values are unique. 
The size of both arrays is the same and can be up to 1000. 
Values in arrays are integers
```

So the answer is `3` pieces for this example.

Here is what I have tried:

```
public int process(int[] inp, int[] desired) {
   int ans = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
      if (inp[i] != desired[i]) ans++;
   }
   return ans;
}
```

My approach is not a correct one, as I am finding elements at each index to count the mismatches. What is the correct approach for solving this problem?

Comment: Integers, means the range is limited only by the type?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko, yes. but need not be a big number, it can be up to 5000 also. There is no special constraint on values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all elements in the given arrays are unique, we can store index the positions of elements in one of these arrays by generating a map of type `Map<Integer,Integer>` associating an array element (*Key*) with its index (*Value*).

Then iterate over the second array, searching for identical chunks.

For that, we need to maintain a variable `prevIndex` that would store the *index* occupied by the previous element in the first array. While iterating, we would need to check each next index in the first array (*corresponding to the next element in the first array*). If the next index differs from the previous only by one - the next element is proved to be a part of a chunk with identical order, and we're just incrementing `prevIndex`. Otherwise, increment the `count` of chunks.

```
public static int process(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> indexByValue = mapIndices(arr2);
    
    int count = 1;
    
    int prevIndex = indexByValue.get(arr1[0]);
    
    for (int i = 1; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        int nextIndex = indexByValue.get(arr1[i]);
        if (nextIndex == prevIndex + 1) {
            prevIndex++;
        } else {
            prevIndex = nextIndex;
            count++;
        }
    }
    
    return count;
}

public static Map<Integer, Integer> mapIndices(int[] arr) {
    
    return IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            i -> arr[i],
            Function.identity()
        ));
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(process(new int[]{1, 4, 3, 2}, new int[]{1, 2, 4, 3}));
}
```

*Output:*

```
3
```